# Kali 2.0 terminal doesn't work

Tags: kali-linux, gnome-terminal

(Sorry for language)

I just installed `Kali Linux 2.0` on a `lenovo z50-70` , just after the installation i opened the terminal (clicking on the terminal icon) but after a bit of loading nothing shows up , i tried re installing gnome and all the needed packets, but nothing changes. i tried to google it and it seems that no one (but me and an online buddy, that also didn't found anything) is actually having some troubles like that

but here comes the interesting thing
I tried to install a different Kali version (32 bits) on a different machine (an Eee pc from asus) and I had the same problem. This thing is literally driving me crazy.

btw I tried all of the following without any results :

```
apt-get update

apt-get upgrade

apt-get install gnome #it wasn't installed yet

apt-get upgrade gnome-terminal #latest version already installed
```

update: i installed a new terminal emulator (terminator) , and it works , but i would really prefere to have back my gnome-terminal , because all the applications links are on the gnome terminal ( as nmap and setoolkit , for example) so it would be great also to know if i can change, for example, nmap, to run on the terminator terminal emulator.

Comment: Hi Tommaso, please remove the solution from the question, add an own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research i found out that this problem is caused by the selection of c ( untrackable english ) language in the installation process, i fixed everything from the settings, changing the language from c (untrackable english language) to english, and logging out and back in.

now it works fine and the terminal starts without any issues

Comment: could you share steps of how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to the virtual terminals using CTRL-ALT-F# (like CTRL-ALT-F1). Once there, you can login and then use cat/head/tail/less to check log files in /var/log to look for errors/issues (or check using the GUI if other parts are working).

F7 will generally get you back to the GUI while 1-6 are generally virtual terminals. In addition, you may want to try re-creating your install media or downloading the ISO again as it's possible there are corruption issues.

In addition, you could try opening gnome-terminal from inside the other terminal to see if any errors/issues are reported to stderr. Finally, try opening gnome-terminal as superuser/root. It's possible it's trying to access files with incorrect or restrictive permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

fixed the problem for me

Comment: If terminal is not opening then where did you typed this command @Evan

Answer (score 0):

On my machine:

> apt-get -f install   is OK

Answer (score -1):

```
apt-get install -y locales locales-all
```

solved the issue for me.